# How to stub a class method inside a function under test using sinon?

Tags: javascript, sinon, jestjs

```
   //Some utility 
   import SomeClass from 'someclass';

   const LoadService = {

     getData(){
     const someClassInstance = new SomeClass('param1', 'param2');
     return someClassInstance.load('param33')
     },

   };

  module.exports =LoadService;
```

The intend is to test LoadService by mocking `SomeClass` as `SomeClass` is already tested. 
I'm using sinon `2.1.0`.

I want to check `getData` method of LoadService. Is it possible to mock `load` class method of `SomeClass`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to mock the `someClass` module so it will return a jest spy and import this module into your test.

```
import SomeClass from 'someClass'
jest.mock('someclass', ()=>jest.fn())
```

then you need to create the spy for the `load` function and for the module itself.

```
const load = jest.fn()
SomeClass.mockImplementation(jest.fn(()=>({load})))
```

after calling the `LoadService` you can check that the module itself and the `load` function were called

```
expect(someClassMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith('param1', 'param2')
expect(load).toHaveBeenCalledWith('param33')
```

So after all there is no need to use Sinon everything can be done using Jest

Comment: I'm calling `getData` on on `LoadService`, but currently, it is calling actual `load` method of `SomeClass` instead of mock.

Comment: Mhmm, that would mean that `SomeClass` is not mocked, could you log what `new SomeClass('param1', 'param2')` returns.

Comment: shouldn't you instruct jest to prepare for mocking the import _before_ doing the import?

Comment: @oligofren this is will be done by jest automatically. So all` jest.mock` calls will be hoisted to the top of the code block at compile time. http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/jest-object.html#jestmockmodulename-factory-options

Comment: Ah, I see. Magic. Not a fan, but each to their own :-)

Comment: @AndreasKöberle Although this works using jest, I'm wondering is there a way to achieve using sinon? `createStubInstance` would work in this case, might be!